# Compute decision boundaries

Tags: r

I used **glmnet** to fit a model now i want compute the estimated decision boundaries. From this Model. Someone can help me to do this.
Daten:

```
library(mvtnorm) # needed for rmvnorm
set.seed(13) # predictability of results

n_1 <- 50
n_2 <- 30
n_3 <- 20

sigma <- cbind(c(1,-0.5), c(-0.5, 2))

mu <- matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = 2)

mu[1, ] <- c(1, 0) # true mean vectors
mu[2, ] <- c(0, 1)
mu[3, ] <- c(-1,-1)

x <- matrix(0, nrow = n_1 + n_2 + n_3 , ncol = 3)

x[, 3] <- rep(1:3, c(n_1, n_2, n_3)) # class labels

x[1:n_1, 1:2] <-
  rmvnorm(n = n_1, mean = mu[1, ], sigma = sigma) # simulate variables
x[(n_1 + 1):(n_1 + n_2), 1:2] <-
  rmvnorm(n = n_2, mean = mu[2, ], sigma = sigma)
x[(n_1 + n_2 + 1):(n_1 + n_2 + n_3), 1:2] <-
  rmvnorm(n = n_3, mean = mu[3, ], sigma = sigma)
```

Logistic regression with the two-dimensional coordinates as input variables

```
install.packages("glmnet")
library(glmnet)

#
mod = glmnet(x[,1:2], x[,3], family = "multinomial", type.multinomial = "grouped")
#plot the resulting object “fit”
plot(mod, xvar = "lambda", label = TRUE, type.coef = "2norm")
```